# TFLite Full Integer Quantization. How can I pass the correct input shape?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, quantization, tflite

I'm trying to do convert a keras LSTM model to TFLite uint8, so I can use it on a Coral TPU.
My inputs are [8000,100,1] shaped time series, with [BATCH_SIZE,STEPS,INPUT_SIZE].
I can't seem to get the right input size after quantization.

The code I use for the full integer quantization si as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r"PATH/TO/KERAS_MODEL")

run_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))

BATCH_SIZE = 8000
STEPS = 100
INPUT_SIZE = 2

def representative_dataset():    
    data = np.random.rand(BATCH_SIZE, STEPS, INPUT_SIZE).astype(np.float32)
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(8000)
    for i in ds.take(1):
        yield {'lstm_input':i}
 
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.experimental_new_converter=True
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()

with open("PATH/TO/TFLITE_MODEL", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_quant_model)
```

I've tried different representative_dataset functions, but every model I get to fully quantize gets an input with shape [1,100,2] instead of [8000,100,2].
How can I get the right shape?
Thanks in advance.